# Homomorphisms between $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory

I have a somewhat naive question to ask. Suppose that $G_1$, $G_2$ are two finite $p$-groups. Is it then true that 
$\mathrm{Hom}(G_1,G_2) = \mathrm{Hom}\left(G_1/\Phi(G_1),G_2\right)$?

Comment: No. Please try some small examples.

Comment: Yes, I am a bit lazy. The point of the question is: isn't it enough to specify how the generators of $G_1$ are mapped? But the generators of $G_1/\Phi(G_1)$ generate $G_1$.

Comment: At any rate, is there a strategy to tackle this problem? Specifying what (or how large) $\mathrm{Hom}(G_1,G_2)$ is, I mean, when $G_1$, $G_2$ are finite $p$-groups.

Comment: @the_fox: That's a very different question. Of course a homomorphism is uniquely determined by the information how it maps any fixed set of generators of $G_1$. This follows immediately from the definitions of "generating set" and "homomorphism". But not all assignments of generators of $G_1$ to elements of $G_2$ can be extended to a homomorphism. This is what group presentations by generators relations are all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, obviously not. Let $G_1=G_2=\mathbb{Z}/p^k$, then ${\rm Hom}\,(G_1,G_2)=\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ and $${\rm Hom}\,(G_1/\Phi(G_1),G_2/\Phi(G_2)) = {\rm Hom}\,(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p) = \mathbb{Z}/p$$

The answer to the edited question is still "no" with the same example: $${\rm Hom}\,(G_1/\Phi(G_1),G_2) = {\rm Hom}\,(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}/p^k) = \mathbb{Z}/p$$

Comment: Sorry, I was carried away. I'll edit my question.

Comment: And I've edited my answer.